# Warning: last line of file ends without newline..... However it does?

Tags: warnings, compiler-warnings

I'm working on a tricky warning and, I just can't seem to get to the bottom of it. Here's what's going on:

I created a header file to define the register addresses for one of my sensor devices. My program works great however, upon compiling the project, I get the warning "device\device_reg.h(44): warning:  #1-D: last line of file ends without a newline"

However, when I go to the file, it does appear to end in a new line. I remember that some text editors sometimes don't appropriately handle enter the newline. So, I deleted the newline, hit the return at the end of the new line, and recompiled. The warning persisted. I repeated this process with notepad++ and the original notepad in windows. Same results...

I am currently compiling c++ code in Keil 5.1.0.0 with an Arm compiler version 5.03.0.76

Any help would be greatly appreciated.

Thank you,
Beau

Answer (score 1):

I had a similar problem with an included file. It turned out that the last line was indented. So when I hit the enter key the next line was indented leaving spaces on the new line. I hit back space to return the last row to the 0 position and the warning went away.

Answer (score 0):

So, it wasn't the solution that I wanted. However, I resolved the issue. I combined the register map definitions with the class header file. I still don't know why I was getting this problem earlier and if anyone has any insights that would be great. However, as for now, this problem is solved.

Thank you.